# Can I add a razer view file in my wwwroot folder and use my controller to point to that .cshtml file and pass my payload?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a working ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC application working. I want to know how I can add a razor view file in my `wwwroot` folder and use my controller to point to that `.cshtml` file and pass my payload?

I'm wondering if I can adjust my controller class to point to a razor view page that resides in `wwwroot`? Right now I have my controller class set up like this:

```
        [Route("~/wwwroot/helloWorld/HelloWorld.cshtml")]
        public IActionResult Index(string pageId)
        {
            switch (pageId)
            {
                case "Foo": 
                    DataModel foo = new DataModel(pageId);
                    return View(foo);

                case "Bar":
                    DataModel bar = new DataModel(pageId);
                    return View(bar);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

I have a hyperlink set up in my `Views/Home/Index.cshtml` like this:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
    <li class="nav-item" style="display: inline-flex; margin-right: .5em; vertical-align:top">
        @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" style="display: inline-flex; margin-right: .5em; vertical-align:top">
        @Html.ActionLink("To Hello World", "Index", "HelloWorld", new { id = "Foo" })
    </li>
</ul>
```

But I get this error every time:

> No webpage was found for the web address:
> https://localhost:5001/wwwroot/helloWorld/HelloWorld.cshtml?id=Foo

Am I doing something wrong or is this just not possible? If it's not possible, I'd like to understand why. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean in the MVC controller, return/redirect to the page (with the data) in the wwwroot folder?

Comment: @ZhiLv yes that's right. For some reason none of the functions for redirect seem to work for cshtml files. It works just fine for html pages though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I get this error every time:
>
> No webpage was found for the web address:
> https://localhost:5001/wwwroot/helloWorld/HelloWorld.cshtml?id=Foo
>
> Am I doing something wrong or is this just not possible? If it's not
> possible, I'd like to understand why. Many thanks in advance.

It is possible to return/redirect the html page in the wwwroot folder from the MVC controller, but it is impossible to transfer the data/model from the controller to the static html page.

Static files, such as HTML, CSS, images, and JavaScript, are assets an ASP.NET Core app serves directly to clients by default. When access them, it will go through the [UseStaticFiles() middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0), instead of via the [asp.net core routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0).